Make Values Display 100% Width of the Table Container
I need each custom_option value to display 100% width of the variations container like this :

I've tried using display block and display flex but it still doesn't work.
.variations .value {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
} 

and
div.custom_option.on {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
}

and the values do not display full width.



.product .entry-summary form.variations_form .variations {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: none;
}

.product .entry-summary .variations {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.product .entry-summary .variations .label, 
.product .entry-summary .variations .value {
    display: block;
}

div.custom_option {
    display: none;
    margin-top: .8235294118rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #1d1d1f;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: 1px solid #86868b;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding: 15px;
}

.variations {
  width: 100%;
}
.variations tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.variations tr th {
  text-align: left;
}

.variations .value .custom_option {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.variations .value {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="label"><label for="memory">Memory</label></th>
      <td class="value">
        <div class="custom_option on is-visible" data-parent-id="memory" data-value="8GB">8GB</div>
        <div class="custom_option is-visible" data-parent-id="memory" data-value="16GB">16GB</div>
        <div class="custom_option is-visible" data-parent-id="memory" data-value="24GB">24GB</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="label"><label for="storage">Storage</label></th>
      <td class="value">
        <div class="custom_option on is-visible" data-parent-id="storage" data-value="256GB">256GB</div>
        <div class="custom_option is-visible" data-parent-id="storage" data-value="512GB">512GB</div>
        <div class="custom_option is-visible" data-parent-id="storage" data-value="1TB">1TB</div>
        <select id="memory" class="" name="attribute_memory" data-attribute_name="attribute_memory" data-show_option_none="yes" style="display: none;">
          <option value="">Choose an option</option>
          <option value="8GB" selected="selected" class="attached enabled">8GB</option>
          <option value="16GB" class="attached enabled">16GB</option>
          <option value="24GB" class="attached enabled">24GB</option>
        </select>
        <select id="storage" class="" name="attribute_storage" data-attribute_name="attribute_storage" data-show_option_none="yes" style="display: none;">
          <option value="">Choose an option</option>
          <option value="256GB" selected="selected" class="attached enabled">256GB</option>
          <option value="512GB" class="attached enabled">512GB</option>
          <option value="1TB" class="attached enabled">1TB</option>
        </select><a class="reset_variations" href="#">Clear</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



Please add enough CSS in the snippet I've created for you in order to reproduce the problem. Added but now it's displaying an error and wanting more content.

Don't see the difference between the two image you've uploaded, you should check and edit post.

Done. post edited with 2 different images

You shouldn't use table's to create lay-outs. Please have a look at "how to create a [mre]"

It uses jQuery to change the html to table elements so i'm stuck with it.

Please add enough CSS in the snippet I've created for you in order to reproduce the problem

You added the wrong image. it should be 2, now i get this error :Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

"You added the wrong image" - Not me, you've posted the exact same 2 images: https://i.sstatic.net/ADVFt.png and https://i.sstatic.net/rnJPJ.png

No, in changed it to the other image. And whenever i try and add more CSS, it asks for more content.

@Mitch Can you try this? https://jsfiddle.net/divyap/fdsaLorn/
